# Does Ramayana have any explicit mention of Dattatreya?

Tags: ramayana, dattatreya

Dattatreya is an incarnation of Brahma-Vishnu-Maheswara together.

Does Valmiki Ramayana have any explicit mention of Dattatreya?

Answer (score 1):

According to texts, wherein the birth of [Sri Dattatreya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dattatreya#Life) was mentioned, Anasuya and Atri are his parents.

Anasuya and Atri appear in the [fag end of Ayodhya Kanda](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/ayodhya/sarga117/ayodhya_117_frame.htm) of Valmiki Ramayana.  However, Sri Dattatreya was not even mentioned therein.

So the answer is Sri Dattatreya was not mentioned in Valmiki Ramayana.

Comment: And Dattatreya was said to have been born in first Mahayuga. So Anasuya and Atri lived until 24th Mahayuga. That's quite a bit

Comment: So the answer is no.